# JavaEE @Specializes annotation usage in inheritence

Tags: cdi

I have below scenario in our project.

```
@Named("a")

class A{ }

@Specializes

class B extends A{ }

@Specializes

class C extends B{ }

class Test{

    @Inject
    A a1;
}
```

In the test class, I want to inject the c class instance to the reference variable a1. I tried and it always injecting B.

How to do this?

```
Some more information:

I also want to mentioned that each of  these 3 classes are in defferent projects. I'm tring to access the method from xhtml file not from Test class I'm using EL .

project1---> A

@Named("links")

@ApplicationScoped

 class A{


 public String getMethod1(){
 }

 }

project2(dependency to project1)----> B

@Specializes

class B extends A{

@Override
public String getMethod1(){
 }

}

project3(dependency to project1,project2)---->C

@Specializes

class C extends B{

@Override
public String getMethod1(){
 }

}

project4(dependency to project1,project2,project3)---> 

MyPage.xhtm



    <ui:include src="#{links.method1()}">

        </ui:include>
```

When I'm trying to access by using EL 'links' always pointing the Class B.

Please advice me here.

Comment: From CDI point of view I can see no problem in your code snippet. It works fine if do this locally. Try sharing some additional information about your code (more about the classes, bean discovery mode etc). Also, just out of curiosity, try adding scopes on your beans.

Comment: Thank you. It should rite?But it's injecting B class instance all the time. My Class A annotated with @ApplicationScoped and B,C are with out any scope.

Comment: Yes, the usage you have is perfectly legit. What CDI version are we talking about? What impl are you using? Are we in SE or EE? What is your bean discovery mode (do you have beans.xml?)?

Comment: We are using JavaEE6(CDI 2) version with WELD implementation and using WebLogicserver. We have beans.xml but inside we configured  only interceptors.

Comment: Just for correction, Java EE6 means you have CDI 1.x. Having `beans.xml` means that your discovery mode will be `all`. Anyway looking at the project structure you added, there might be something fishy there. Your `project4` should only depend on `project3` maybe? Since the rest of dependencies will be brought in transitively? I will try a similar structure locally and get back to you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with my project structure with multiple maven modules. It lead to transitive dependency of the modules.